# Interpretation of Lincoln's speech Second Inaugural Address "as was said three thousand years ago",

Tags: meaning

What does the phrase "as was said three thousand years ago" mean in Lincoln's Second Inaugural Address?

> Yet, if God wills that it continue, until all the wealth piled by the bond-man's two hundred and fifty years of unrequited toil shall be sunk, and until every drop of blood drawn with the lash, shall be paid by another drawn with the sword, **as was said three thousand years ago,** so still it must be said:"The judgments of the Lord, are true and righteous altogether.

What happened 3000 years ago?

Answer (score 1):

The line is a quote from [Psalm 19](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psalm_19), line 9.

The book of [Psalms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psalms) is traditionally said to be composed by King David.

[King David](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David) supposedly reigned circa 1000 BC.  Which is 'three thousand years ago'. Actually about 2900 years before Lincoln, but lets not quibble.

So the thing that happened three thousand years ago was David reigned and wrote the line Lincoln quoted.

Comment: That was very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: You can accept my answer as correct by clicking on the checkmark.